# What noun means "an unabashed, incorrigible person"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Let's say I know a person that unabashedly engages in behavior that is seen as undesirable (but not necessarily immoral or eccentric; for example, someone that is very brazenly nerdy). I am specifically focused on this person exhibiting such behavior without embarrassment or regard for others' opinions, i.e. someone that is not afraid to stand out. Is there a word (noun) for such a person, preferably one without strong negative connotations?

Some words I think don't quite work:

- "Nerd" (and e.g. "geek", "dork", etc.) suggests a specific behavior/trait that isn't correct for my usage, and *doesn't* usually suggest brazenness.
- "Reprobate" has strong overtones of immorality. "Libertine" similarly has negative connotations.
- "Rebel", "renegade" and "maverick" all suggest that the person is actively violating rules, which isn't necessarily the case (and, again, are often seen as negative).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117628/discussion-on-question-by-matthew-what-noun-means-an-unabashed-incorrigible-pe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [exhibitionist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exhibitionist) would generally imply someone who isn't shy, but generally implies a particular action which doesn't match the question.

A [flouter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flouter) is getting closer, but has similar issues as a rebel; it may imply that *laws* are being flouted rather than simply the opinions of others.

The best term may be [individualist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/individualist); in particular:

> Someone who does as they wish, unconstrained by external influences.

Fear of others' opinions would certainly qualify as an external influence.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a *brazenface*

> = an impudent or shameless person
>
> [Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Brazenface)

> adjectivally: *brazen-faced* = Bold and without shame
>
> Lexico Oxford

The word is related to:

> *brass neck* = a type of behaviour where someone is extremely confident about their own actions but does not understand that their behaviour is unacceptable to others
>
> "She's got a brass neck to ask for a day off when we're so busy"
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brass-neck)

The etymology is reasonably clear and related to:

> brazen (adj.) Old English bræsen "of brass," from bræs "brass" (see brass (n.)) + -en (2). The figurative sense of "hardened in effrontery" is from 1570s (in brazen-faced), *perhaps suggesting a face unable to show shame*. To brazen it "face impudently" is from 1550s. Related: Brazenly.
>
> [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/brazen)

Comment: All covered before on related threads (eg [an adjective or noun for someone who has a lot of gall](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263755/an-adjective-or-noun-for-someone-who-has-a-lot-of-gall), almost certainly duplicates. brazen, audacious, brass-neck ... ... has a lot of nerve.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, but see my reply to your other recent comment. I don't think we will ever completely agree on this. For those asking questions, life may be too short to scour the archives of the site.

Comment: To put it bluntly, ELU is not intended to be primarily a Q and A site. It has higher ideals. There _are_ Q and A sites where those not interested in observing such interests may freely answer without bothering about whether they're contributing to bloat.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I don't see any nouns in that question. Also, if ELU isn't supposed to be a Q&A site, it sure picked a strange platform. (What *is* it supposed to be?)

Comment: @Matthew 'Brazenface' has appeared before, even though the free online dictionaries it appears in are Websters 1913 edition, and a citation of this warning that it might archaic or even obsolete. Google Ngrams show that it has occurred very rarely since 1880. // The question would be a duplicate were it not for the 'no overtones of immorality' caveat here (which probably means there will be no answers: 'impudent' and 'shameless'  certainly indicate disapproval. // You omitted 'primarily', thus misquoting. One is left wondering whether this was merely carelessness.